# Why is my fortran routine passing an incorrect value to my C++ function?

Tags: c++, fortran, mpi, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a fortran routine calling a C++ function in an external static library. I have an integer:

```
integer (c_int) :: processor_wall_point_count
```

That is simply being passed to a function:

```
print*, processor_wall_point_count         ! gives 112
call fci_wmm_allocate_domain(processor_wall_point_count, wall_model_ray_point_count)
```

The C++ function:

```
void fci_wmm_allocate_domain(int* _processor_wall_point_count, int* _ray_point_count)
{
    std::cout << *_processor_wall_point_count << std::endl; // gives 70
}
```

The main code has an MPI environment, and when run on 10 processors with

```
print*, process_id, processor_wall_point_count !process id, variable
call MPI_Barrier()
call fci_wmm_allocate_domain(processor_wall_point_count, wall_model_ray_point_count)
```

and in C++:

```
void fci_wmm_allocate_domain(int* _processor_wall_point_count, int* _ray_point_count)
{
    std::cout << process_id << ", " <<*_processor_wall_point_count << std::endl;
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

I get the following:

```
       8          32
       9           0
       0          16
       2          48
       6           0
       1           0
       3          16
       5           0
       7           0
       4           0
2, 48
8, 32
0, 10
3, 16
5, 0
9, 0
6, 0
1, 0
7, 0
4, 0
```

I.e., all the values are passed correctly except for processor 0. I have used the C bindings before without (too many) problems. What is going on here?

EDIT: here is the fortran interface:

```
interface
    subroutine fci_wmm_allocate_domain(point_count_F, ray_points_F) bind (c)
        use iso_c_binding
        integer (c_int), intent(in)    :: point_count_F, ray_points_F
    end subroutine fci_wmm_allocate_domain
end interface
```

ISSUE:
I'm not sure how I missed thism but I had the folllowing function being called upstream only on processor 0:

```
void print_node_info(void)
{
    if (is_node_root_process && verbose)
    {
        std::cout << "[I] Node " << node_name << " (0x";
        std::cout << std::hex << processor_node_id;
        std::cout << ") has root process " << current_node_root_process_id << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Changing to

```
void print_node_info(void)
{
    if (is_node_root_process && verbose)
    {
        std::cout << "[I] Node " << node_name << " (0x";
        std::cout << std::hex << processor_node_id << std::dec;
        std::cout << ") has root process " << current_node_root_process_id << std::endl;
    }
}
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: @francescalus Whoops, I meant to include that. Editing now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is interesting that 112 = 0x70 and 16 = 0x10. Could it be a forgotten C++ stream manipulator (`std::hex`) somewhere?